# Typedef for static method

Tags: c++, typedef

Is it possible to create a typedef for method? I mean:

```
//namespace A{
//namespace B{
Car& Car::getInstance() //static! (sigleton)
{
  if(m_instance == nullptr)
  {
    m_instance = new Car();
  }
  return *m_instance;
}
//}
//}

// something like:
typedef A::B::Car::getInstance() l_car;
```

And now :

```
l_car.fake_method();
```

Solution? :
Pointer to function after that typedef?

Answer (score 3):

The typedef for a pointer to the *static* method:

```
Car& Car::getInstance()
```

is the same as a regular function pointer, and would look like:

```
typedef Car& (*CarMethod)();
```

You'd use it like:

```
CarMethod getCar = &Car::getInstance;
//...
Car& theCar = (*getCar)();
```

I'm not sure what use this is in a Singleton, though.

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` (as you can guess from the name) is about types, not values. You can however do

```
Car& Car::getInstance() {
    static Car *p = new Car;
    return *p;
}

Car& l_car = getInstance();
```

but there's no way you can create the singleton instance at the first use of `l_car`, except of course with a macro trick:

```
#define l_car (Car::getInstance())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
A::B::Car& l_car = A::B::Car::getInstance();
```

Comment: A::B::Car& l_car = A::B::Car::getInstance();